# Test if a 3D data point is inside an ellipsoid

Tags: matlab, 3d, rotation

I have 3D data and a function to define an Ellipsoid around the data. I want to test if some other data falls inside the ellipsoid. The ellipsoid is rotated and I have the 3x3 rotation matrix.

The form of the Ellipsoid is as below:

```
Ax^2 + By^2 + Cz^2 + 2Dxy + 2Exz + 2Fyz + 2Gx + 2Hy + 2Iz = 1
```

and I get these outputs.

```
% Output: 
% * center - ellispoid center coordinates [xc; yc; zc] 
% * ax - ellipsoid radii [a; b; c] 
% * evecs - ellipsoid radii directions as columns of the 3x3 matrix 
% * v - the 9 parameters describing the ellipsoid algebraically: 
% Ax^2 + By^2 + Cz^2 + 2Dxy + 2Exz + 2Fyz + 2Gx + 2Hy + 2Iz = 1
```

Can anyone tell me how I check if a point is inside the ellipsoid?

Thanks
Larry

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about understanding a geometric formula, not about programming.

Answer (score 2):

If

```
Ax^2 + By^2 + Cz^2 + 2Dxy + 2Exz + 2Fyz + 2Gx + 2Hy + 2Iz
```

Is greater than 1 you're outside, if it is smaller, you're inside. This is the whole point of this formula.